# How to use schooling years information to better identify the returns to education

Tags: regression

Assume that you have the dates of birth of the individuals in the dataset. Imagine that in 1985, the Ghanaian government has decided to raise the school leaving age from 10 to 15 years old. How would you use that information to better identify the returns to education (describe identification strategy, method, underlying assumption)?

Comment: Is this a question in a problem set?

Comment: Please indicate additional information.